arrows convergence
I want to make the tips of the arrow next to  converge with each other with a little bit of space between them. Also, I would like the arrows to be thicker.
These are the code lines I used:
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Drawing the valence band
    \fill[cyan!90] (-2,0) rectangle (2,0.5);
    \draw[thick] (-2,0) -- (2,0) node[midway, below, yshift=-2mm] {Valence band};
    
    % Drawing the conduction band
    \draw[thick] (-2,2) -- (2,2) node[midway, above, yshift=2mm] {Conduction band};

    % Drawing the energy gap label
    \draw[<->] (2.2,0) -- (2.2,2) node[midway, right] {$E_g \sim 1 \text{ eV}$};
    
    % Drawing electrons in the conduction band
    \filldraw[black] (-1.5,2) circle (2pt);
    \filldraw[black] (-0.5,2) circle (2pt);
    \filldraw[black] (0.5,2) circle (2pt);
    \filldraw[black] (1.5,2) circle (2pt);
    
    % Drawing holes in the valence band
    \filldraw[white, thick] (-1.5,0.25) circle (2pt);
    \draw[thick] (-1.5,0.25) circle (2pt);
    
    \filldraw[white, thick] (-0.5,0.25) circle (2pt);
    \draw[thick] (-0.5,0.25) circle (2pt);
    
    \filldraw[white, thick] (0.5,0.25) circle (2pt);
    \draw[thick] (0.5,0.25) circle (2pt);
    
    \filldraw[white, thick] (1.5,0.25) circle (2pt);
    \draw[thick] (1.5,0.25) circle (2pt);
    
   
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Schematic energy band representation of a semiconductor}
\end{figure}

Thank you in advance.

Please can you complete your snippet so it can be compiled? I don't understand what you mean about making the arrow tips converge next to E_g. Assuming the image shows your current output, there are no tips next to E_g and the only tips there are are at opposite ends of a straight line, so it is hard to see how they should converge.

It isn't clear to me whether this is the same as your previous question, even though it concerns the same diagram. We tell people one question-per-question, after all, and this question seems to concern a arrows and lines rather than nodes and labels. Could you clarify what you want? Are you using Zarko's answer? If this is a different question, it can be re-opened, but it would be good to give the community a sense of whether the previous answer helped you or not.
