\draw arrows convergence
I want to make the tips of the arrow illustrating the enerhy gap level converge with each other with a little bit of space between them, just like I drew. Also, I would like the arrows to be thicker.
These are the code lines I used:
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Drawing the valence band
\fill[cyan!90] (-2,0) rectangle (2,0.5);
\draw[thick] (-2,0) -- (2,0) node[midway, below, yshift=-2mm] {Valence band};

% Drawing the conduction band
\draw[thick] (-2,2) -- (2,2) node[midway, above, yshift=2mm] {Conduction band};

% Drawing the energy gap label
\draw[<->] (2.2,0) -- (2.2,2) node[midway, right] {$E_g \sim 1 \text{ eV}$};

% Drawing electrons in the conduction band
\filldraw[black] (-1.5,2) circle (2pt);
\filldraw[black] (-0.5,2) circle (2pt);
\filldraw[black] (0.5,2) circle (2pt);
\filldraw[black] (1.5,2) circle (2pt);

% Drawing holes in the valence band


\filldraw[white, thick] (-1.5,0.25) circle (2pt);
\draw[thick] (-1.5,0.25) circle (2pt);

\filldraw[white, thick] (-0.5,0.25) circle (2pt);
\draw[thick] (-0.5,0.25) circle (2pt);

\filldraw[white, thick] (0.5,0.25) circle (2pt);
\draw[thick] (0.5,0.25) circle (2pt);

\filldraw[white, thick] (1.5,0.25) circle (2pt);
\draw[thick] (1.5,0.25) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Schematic energy band representation of a semiconductor}
\end{figure}

Thank you in advance.


You repeat almost the same question again and again. It seems that now it is time, that you start to read tikz package documentation. For start the first tutorial and than part III: TikZ ist kein Zeichenprogramm, especially chapter Arrows. Drawing arrows is so elementary that in the case, that showed code fragment you write yourself, than code for simple arrow should not be a problem.

Please use the Edit button to edit your questions rather than re-asking them. Please also see how I formatted your code in the previous copy of this question. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/722378/arrows-convergence You can edit a question even if it has been closed and it will be considered for re-opening.

I suggest to listen to the experienced users commented before me. FYI: open tikz.dev https://tikz.dev/
